# React native application cannot add member to an existing getStream channel

Tags: getstream-io

I am creating an app where I use stream API (getstream-io).
So, in my app a channel is created by one user for chat and then a second user tries to fetch that channel by its channel id, to add himself to the channel.
The `queryChannels` method fails with the below error :

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: StreamChat error code 70: QueryChannels failed with error: "1 channels match your query but cannot be returned because you don't have access to them. Did you forget to include {members: $in: ["fec7bc90-260e-41c4-bef1-1dbe695e082b"]}?"
```

I tried to follow the steps mentioned in the the thread [How to make a user able to join a channel using the channel's ID with getstream-io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77138572/how-to-make-a-user-able-to-join-a-channel-using-the-channels-id-with-getstream) but still I get the same error.

Could anyone provide further help to resolve this.

I tried to call `queryChannels` as below :

```
        const filter = { id: { $eq: 'someId' } }
        const channels = await chatClient.queryChannels(filter)
```

Expected to get the channel with the id, but instead got below error :

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: StreamChat error code 70: QueryChannels failed with error: "1 channels match your query but cannot be returned because you don't have access to them. Did you forget to include {members: $in: ["fec7bc90-260e-41c4-bef1-1dbe695e082b"]}?"
```